# Why value sent to Text box gets disappeared in web application

Tags: selenium, web-applications, automation, robotframework

I am trying to Input text into text box using the Robot framework selenium library and the same gets vanished just after typing. The script passes but the value is not actually passed

input text

```
//*[text()="Daily Order Limit"]/../../../input    150
```

I have tried to put more, Click the element and then Input text, Wait until element visible/enabled.

Comment: Please share the HTML code ?

Comment: Have a look at [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly in order to receive relevant answers

Comment: Thank you :) Here is the HTML code of object..  <input aria-invalid="false" name="limit" placeholder="Daily Order Limit" type="number" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="">

Answer (score 0):

If this the HTML Code of text box element

```
<input aria-invalid="false" name="limit" placeholder="Daily Order Limit" 
type="number" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value="">
```

You can use the below mentioned xpath

```
Input Text   //input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input']   150

            OR

Input Text    //input[@placeholder='Daily Order Limit']    150
```

Comment: HI.. I tried both the options  - it neither worked by changing Xpath nor be sending explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

You see the text getting filled in, but it disappears after typing? Sounds like the page is not fully loaded yet, as in the input is loaded but some ajax/javascript/... refreshes the page. Normaly you wouldn't noticr but Selenium is SO fast that it happens.

Try this:
Sleep 5s
//*[text()="Daily Order Limit"]/../../../input 150

Note that Sleep or hard waits in general are a bad solution. If this works, the next step is figuring out how to detect when the page is REALLY finished loading.

Comment: Thank you for your response:) I tried to keep wait max of 20s, it didnt work. I see that the value is keyed in the text field but gets disappeared .

Comment: Is it a public website? I would like to have a look myself. And to make sure, what I mean is: after the PREVIOUS action do a hard 20 second wait. NOT findElement/clickable, just count to 20.

Comment: Taco Verhagen.. It is not a public site though! If I add step to validate if element is visible, it gets passed.